# Autoclicking within a website on load

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension which fires a set of clicks (select size, add to cart) - I am currently using [this](https://store.nike.com/ca/en_gb/pd/air-vapormax-running-shoe/pid-12022334/pgid-12082853) website to test.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(
// autoClick then add to cart
setTimeout(setSize, 250);
)

function setSize() {
  $("span[class*=js-selectBox-value nsg-form--drop-down--selected-option]").val('(US 7)');
}
```

This only selects the size. Since I've noticed that the span with class `js-selectBox-value nsg-form--drop-down--selected-option` is filled in when selecting the size, I assumed that just editing this value would be alright, but it is not working.

Comment: `setTimout()` takes a function and an integers as params. Not a string and an integer

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout("setSize", 250);
```

change this to

```
setTimeout(setSize, 250);
```

setTimeout first argument is function not string.

Comment: Thanks, edited. But I still don't see the value being manipulated.